# subclassing the TimedRotatingFileHandler to send the rotated logfile as mail

Tags: python, python-logging

Hey everybody and welcome to my coding problem!

I'm using python logging and rotate the logfile every midnight. It works.

Now I want to send the log every day before rotating. No Problem, I just use subclassing as you can see below.

But the Problem is, I am getting 8 Mails per rotation an I don't know why. It's always the same Mail.

I'm running the code on a Windows 2019 Serer and I packed it to an exe file with pyinstaller. The program is started with the nssm, the non sucking service manager.

Do you have any ideas?

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler
import json

#my own mail module
from mail import send_email

# Import config
with open("conf.json") as f:
    config = json.load(f)

# Configure logging settings
log_filename = "log.txt"
log_days_to_keep = 7  # Number of days to keep log files
log_formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s")


# Custom TimedRotatingFileHandler with email notification
class EmailNotificationTimedRotatingFileHandler(TimedRotatingFileHandler):
    def __init__(
        self,
        filename,
        when="midnight",
        interval=1,
        backupCount=log_days_to_keep,
        encoding=None,
        delay=False,
        utc=False,
    ):
        super().__init__(filename, when, interval, backupCount, encoding, delay, utc)

    def doRollover(self):
        if config["E-Mail Konfiguration"]["enable"] == "True":
            send_email(
                subject="wh-sync Log",
                msg_text="Log file has been rotated",
                logging=logging,
                attachment_file_name=self.baseFilename,
            )
        super().doRollover()


# Create a timed rotating file handler
file_handler = EmailNotificationTimedRotatingFileHandler(
    log_filename, when="midnight", interval=1, backupCount=log_days_to_keep
)
file_handler.setFormatter(log_formatter)

# Set the log level and add the handler to the root logger
logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.INFO,
    format="%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s",
    handlers=[file_handler],
)
```